# Data to send to database?

Tags: php, html, database

I am using an OTP generation for one of my client. I have done with below coding but I need to send the data to database where the data should be stored after verifying the OTP. Below is the code which I have tried and the OTP works for me.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    session_set_cookie_params(180);


    $smsgatewaycenter_com_url = "http://URL/api/v3/?"; //SMS Gateway Center API URL
    //$smsgatewaycenter_com_mask = "SGCSMS"; //Your Approved Sender Name / Mask
    $api_key = "apikey";



    function smsgatewaycenter_com_Send($mobile, $sendmessage, $debug=false){
        global $smsgatewaycenter_com_url,$api_key;
        //$parameters = 'UserName='.$smsgatewaycenter_com_user;
       // $parameters.= '&Password='.$smsgatewaycenter_com_password;
        $parameters.= 'method=sms';
        $parameters.= '&api_key='.$api_key;
        $parameters.= '&to='.urlencode($mobile);
        $parameters.= '&sender=VLDEMO';
        $parameters.= '&message='.urlencode($sendmessage);
        $apiurl =  $smsgatewaycenter_com_url.$parameters;
        $ch = curl_init($apiurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($debug) {
            echo "Response: <br><pre>" . $curl_scraped_page . "</pre><br>";
        }
        return($curl_scraped_page);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //      Function to generate and append OTP code within the message        //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function smsgatewaycenter_com_OTP($length = 8, $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789'){
        $chars_length = (strlen($chars) - 1);
        $string = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
        for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i = strlen($string)){
            $r = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
            if ($r != $string{$i - 1}) $string .=  $r;
        }
        return $string;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //           If Debug is set to true below, then response from             //
    //         SMSGatewayCenter.com API will be printed on the screen          //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $debug = true; //Set to true if you want to see the response

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //     If user has not posted anything, lets load the user login page      //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (empty($_POST)){
        $i = 0;
        echo '  
        <html>
<head>
<title>Droom Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<style>
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="row" style="background-image: url(images/Background_final.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: cover; ">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4" >
<div style="padding:10px;text-align: center;background-color:#5e97f2;">
<h4 style="text-size:28px;font-weight:800;color:#fff;">Get Assistance</h4>
</div>
<form name="leadform" method="post" data-toggle="validator" onsubmit="return validateform()" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom: 20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your full name" id="example-text-input" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-email-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email id" id="example-email-input" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-tel-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">City</label>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city" id="example-tel-input" required>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-datetime-local-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
  <div class="col-4">
  <select class="form-group" name="category" required>
  <option>---Select--</option>
  <option>Cars</option>
  <option>Bikes</option>
  <option>Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-search-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Mobile Number</label>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mobilenumber" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" id="example-search-input" required>
  </div>
</div>
<input type=submit name="sendsms" value="Get OTP" OnClick="smsgatewaycenter_com_Send(this.form);">

<!--<button type="submit" class="submit hide" id="add">Submit</button>-->

<div>
<!--<input type="submit" id="add" value="Submit">-->
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-right:0pc;padding-left:0px;">
<img src="images/transparent.png" class="img-responsive" style="height:480px;"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</header>
<section>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h4 style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:32px;padding-top:40px;text-align: center;">Because you dont buy a car everyday!</h4>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-3">
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/widest_selection.png"/>
<p style="font-size:16px;"><b>Widest Selection</b></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/lowest_price.png" width="150" height="150"/>
<p style="font-size:16px;"><b>Lowest Price Guranteed</b></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/verified_seller.png"/>
<p style="font-size:16px;"><b>Verified Seller</b></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/buyer_protection.png"/>
<p style="font-size:16px;"><b>100% Buyer Protection</b></p>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</section>
<footer>
<p style="font-size:15px;text-align:center;">Copyright &copy; 2017 | All rights reserved</p>
</footer>





</body>
</html>';
    }


    if (isset($_POST['sendsms'])){
        $_SESSION['smsgatewaycenterotp'] = smsgatewaycenter_com_OTP(); //Generate OTP

        $username = $_POST['firstname'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobilenumber'];

            smsgatewaycenter_com_Send($mobile,'Dear '.$firstname.'! Please authenticate your OTP. Your One Time password is: '.$_SESSION['smsgatewaycenterotp'],$debug);
            echo '
            <html>
                <body>
                    <h1>Authenticate OTP (One Time Password)</h1>
                    <p>We have sent an SMS to your registered phone number, please authenticate your one time password entering below.</p>
                    <form method="POST">
                    <table border=1>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Your one time password (OTP):</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="getsmsgatewaycenterotp"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type=submit name="submitotp" value="Authenticate OTP"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>';;

    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['submitotp'])){

        $sgc_otp = $_POST['getsmsgatewaycenterotp'];
        if($_SESSION['smsgatewaycenterotp'] == $sgc_otp){
            echo '
            <html>
                <body>
                    <h2>You\'ve been successfully verified your One-Time Password</h2>
                </body>
            </html>';
        } else {
            echo'
            <html>
                <body>
                    <h2>Wrong Password!</h2>
                </body>
            </html>';
        }
    }
```

After this code works the data should be send to database. Please can any one help me how to do this. This is my first project in the PHP. Help needed.

Comment: What issue you are exactly facing ?

Comment: There is no database related code here. You should write it yourself and post back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz My issue is I don't know where to include the database and Post the data to the database.

Comment: Inside your php code, where you are using curl to hit the API url and then get the response. If response is OK then store the OTP and its associated data in database for verification purpose.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz can you help me  how to do it in the code please.

Comment: Is this code live or you are using it in local ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz its in local.

Comment: Give me your email id so that I can send you some help code

Comment: @Mayank this is my mail id ritu44402@gmail.com

Comment: Check the answer section

Comment: Get some more reputation points so that you can start chatting with some one. 9 more points are required to start chat.

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

```
$message = 'your message with OTP';
$mobile = 'mobile number';
$url = 'URL of your SMS API with urlencode() message in it';

try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $APIresponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $res = json_decode($APIresponse, true);     // API response
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $response['ErrorCode']  = 2;
    $response['ErrorMsg']   = 'Error in SMS API';
}

if($res['ErrorCode'] == '000')                  // API Response is OK means OTP send on given mobile number
{
    // make a sql query to insert mobile number, otp, text message in database
}
```

Comment: This code helped me. And Can you say me in the above code in the question how to make a pop up while entering for OTP

Comment: Are you still stuck with this problem?

Comment: The data is working fine and it stores into database.

Comment: Try this: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I want to use like this examples <a href="https://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/">link</a>

Comment: I want to use the example in this type https://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Comment: Whats is the issue in using this?

Comment: I will explain you properly. I have a lead form where the user should enter all the feilds and after submitting they need to click on Get OTP button. The page gets refreshed and the lead form get's hide and OTP part will display. And my expected output should be I need a pop-up after submitting the form to enter the OTP feild. But I have doubt I didn't write the OTP code in another page, all the code has been written in one PHP page itself.

Comment: In that case the best way to manage thing is use jquery and ajax, its a life saver

Comment: It is a big topic, I can't explain you here.

Comment: Do you have this code on server??

Comment: Yes I have it in the server

Comment: Can you give me your mail id

Comment: Please check your mail id